# Send and receive phone call and SMS on a computer?

Tags: voip, phone

I am currently in mainland China, I want to send and receive phone call& SMS on a computer.

I tried Google Voice as well as Skype. Their outgoing call is all right, but it seems impossible to get a fixed mainland China phone number for both services.

So I turned into alternative solutions, but is there some kind of hardware that I can plug into my computer or my router, so I can insert my SIM card into that hardware and it provides a service over my LAN for my to send/receive phone call/SMS, so all my Internet devices(tablets/desktop/laptop) can use?

Comment: Just Google for ᴘᴄɪ or M.2 ʟᴛᴇ modules and you’ll get what you want (many manufacturers)… For 5G enabled calling, I’m suggesting the Telit ꜰɴ980m http://4gltemall.com/5g/5g-module.html. If you want to avoid data only cards, look for ᴄꜱꜰʙ or ᴠoʟᴛᴇ among the card features. Windows 10 along Android should allow natively what you want without having to install third‑party apps. For other systems just look at the more powerful Asterisk in order to build a gateway and perform a lot of more (like automatic robot calling agent)…

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called PopMyPhone that works on Android phones.

It allows you to send/receive SMS from your computer. It works using email so anything that can read email can get SMS messages, you can reply to the email and the SMS will get sent from your phone.

You can also see who called you, if anyone used your phone to dial a call, or if anyone answered a call on your phone.

Take a look at www.popmyphone.com or search in the Google Play Store

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I wanted, I want to make calls and receive them, that's the most important part

Answer (score 0):

[VoIP phone systems](http://www.telecom.toshiba.com/) have a lot many applications that is supported by a PC and works on Internet protocol. These applications help in answering a call and viewing SMS on the PC. the best example is Skype which works on VoIP technology.

Comment: Unfortunately because of political issues in China, private companies like Skype cannot get a proper lisence for participating in telecommunication bussiness, so you cannot have a Chinese Skype-in phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I have from time to time researched this issue, but I could never find exactly some answer related to this kind of setup. This is because the phone-industry terminology is unknown to me, and whenever I would search for this, I would always find answers about VoIP/SIP or about PBX and Asterisk.

But I was never able to find something about setting-up your own telephone-gateway, without connecting to a SIP provider.
(Basically, I wanted to know how you can be SIP provider)

Fortunately today is my lucky day, as I found these links as a starting point:

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/VoIP+Gateways

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_service_%28telecommunications%29#Foreign_exchange_office

http://www.x100p.com/products/FXO.php

Especially the last link is very useful, with an example of an actual FXO card (it's the first time I hear this term, it seems it's only known by VoIP professionals, and it's kept quite "hidden" from the consumers ears)

Now I still have to learn which software to use for this setup. (From the last link it looks like Asterisk has builtin support, but I have to check it.)

Comment: So basically what I need is to plug in a PCI card with an FXO interface into my computer and setup software, then I'm good to go?

Comment: @CarlLee, I suppose so, but I haven't tried it yet. Plus, I'm not sure where (or whether) you can find the software. (especially the appropriate drivers)

Comment: It seems that Cisco had an equipment which did exactly this, but it's too bad they discontinued it: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/unified-communications/spa3102-voice-gateway-router/index.html